# Is 100 Mbps enough to drive 7 Remote Desktop connections?

Tags: remote-desktop

We are designing a new network set up for the office. We have 20 PCs which are going to be connected via Remote Desktop to one server running Windows Server 2012. Those 20 PCs will be connected to three 100 Mbps 8-port switches which use the gigabit connection of the server.

Here comes the question - is 100 Mbps enough to drive 7 Remote Desktop connections? Those connections are going to be used for basic stuff like browsing the internet and working with documents.

I stumbled upon a benchmark from 2008 by Microsoft which shows that even at relatively heavy loads an RD connection uses just 1 Mbps, the worst case scenario being 4 Mbps. However, I want to be sure, so I'm asking you guys.

Thank you!

Comment: Given the price difference between 100 and 1gigabit equipment being that 100mbit is not cheaper - why bother? Did you get the switches from a garbage sale? Motherboards have gigabit ethernet ports and the price for a gigabit switch is so cheap - I would fire anyone coming up with a scheme like this. What if the requirements change?

Comment: Well, we already have 100 Mbps switches, that's why we chose not to buy gigabit ones. The requirements will never change. But just now I changed my mind and decided that I will buy gigabit switches given their low price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the fact that it usually depends on the actual resolution and various aspects like sound transmitting, 100 Mbps will be more than enough to handle the traffic for 7 RDP connections.

Although the whole scheme with three eight-port switches seems to be unclear and questionable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you mind elaborating why using 3 switches is questionable? Do you mean that the way the server connects to those switches is questionable? If this is the case, here's the whole deal - we have wall-mounted ethernet outlets which the server and the switches are going to be connected to.

Comment: This way you are creating traffic bottlenecks. Although they won't interfere with RDP, since RDP isn't consuming much of the bandwidth, other types of traffic may be affected. Furthermore, there cannot be more permanent thing than a "temporary solution", so I'm sure this setup will create lot of issues in future. Not with RDP though.

Comment: Alright, I'll take your word for it. 100 Mbps is truly slow for a local network although it would do a fine job in our case. I will buy gigabit switches instead of using the 100 Mbps ones we have now. They aren't very expensive anyway. Also, I'll buy a NIC for the server with 4 gigabit ports and connect the switches to those. Thank you!

Comment: No need for the later. Any server sold in the last 10 years or so will have 1-2 gigabit ports ANYWAY. Why waste money?

Comment: The idea behind the NIC was to provide a true gigabit connection to each of the switches instead of all switches sharing the same gigabit connection. And such NICs are cheap anyway. Given your input, we won't buy a NIC right away. Instead, we'll see how things are going using the server's integrated gigabit port/s first and buy a NIC if needed.

Comment: You are placing a softrouter, which will be hard to get rid of. If it will be acting as a bridge - this is one complication. If it won't act as a bridge - that's another (subnetting). This approach basically converts the initial funding to additional engineering workhours (which consumes time, thus money), and what's worst - these workhours won't be a one-time thing, they will be a permanent addition. Buy hardware, it's cheaper in the end.